# Joomla 2.5 and Global Configuration admin page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7, joomla2.5, suphp

WE recently upgrade our site from Joomla 1.7 to Joomla 2.5. Everything seems to be working fine, except one single page, which is the global configuration page. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Elb.jpg

I have tried reuploading the administrator files and have checked permissions. Any idea?

Comment: Did you clean the joomla cache ? It looks like it's not using the CSS file.

Comment: If I look at the source it is not loading anything in the header file, and console says: Joomla is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)

Answer (score 3):

I think the Javascript and CSS files used within the site changed but the names of these files remained the same. The upshot is that your web browser is continuing to use previously downloaded versions of the files.

It isn't the Joomla cache that it causing the issue - it is the browser cache. Next time you are in the /administrator/ area click the refresh/reload button while holding down the shift key on the keyboard. If you are using Google Chrome hold the Ctrl key instead - and you may have to do this twice - but no more. If it isn't working after two goes then the fault lies elsewhere.

If your problem isn't solved by the above - view the source of the HTML on the page that is a problem. You will probably find errors or warnings in the html that are breaking functionality. It may be that there is a fatal error somewhere towards the end of the page too - if this was output in the middle of a html tag it may not be visible until you view source.

Alternatively you may be hitting a fatal error and your server may be set to not show errors - in that case check your server's error log. Your hosting control panel may have a 'last 50 errors' output so if you log into your hosting control panel in one tab, trigger the error in another and then click through to the 'last 50 errors' area of the control panel you may be able to quickly see the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error log. I had my global configuration page looking exactly like yours. It turned out the errors was this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class JDatabaseMySQLi in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/libraries/joomla/database/database/mysqli.php original.backup on line 567, referer: http://www.example.com/administrator/index.php
```

I had a (1) file named `mysqli.php original.php` in `/libraries/joomla/database/database` which is a backup of `mysqli.php` in the same folder. It turns out joomla parses all files in the folder as php files and therefore the *redeclare* error. I put the file in a subdir and the problem was solved.